# submit in rails without formhelpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and still learning the ropes via railstutorial, but the book does all changes to the db via form submissions (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). But how would I go about submitting (updating the db) without this, lets say I want to add some score which is computed on page ,(for example via a js counter - for simplicity lets just say its a constant 10) and my db consists of a column called score. Then after pressing a submit button how would I go about updating the db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two trivial ways:

- Use a form
- Use a URL parameter with a link

The processing (other than GET v. POST) on the Rails side is identical--it's just a parameter.

If you're using JavaScript, there's not necessarily a reason to *not* use a form, though, since you could just update a form input element and submit normally.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, actually.

1. The constant 10 is submitted from the view. The submit needs to point to the controller action that will handle this request. So the submit button should build the url using `:controller`, `:action`, `:id` parameters. In a form, this is handled in the `form_for` declaration. You will deal with in the `button_tag` declaration.
2. The routes should be configured so that this message can reach the controller/ action.
3. The constant 10 is transported in the params hash. If the field is my_counter, then look for `params[:my_counter]`. If the form had been for a model, say tweets, then it might be in `params[:tweet][:my_counter]`.
4. In the controller action, possibly update, you will first fetch the record to change with something like `@score = Score.find(:params[:id])`. This `params[:id]` is also coming from the view with the submit. Change the counter here, and save.

   ```
   def update
     @score = Score.find(:params[:id])
     @score.counter = params[:my_counter]
     @score.save
     redirect_to :action => :index  # or wherever
   end
   ```

Good luck.